# How to apply Datetime comparison on varchar Datatype in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to apply datetime comparison on a field which is of type varchar in SQL Server database. I want to know how can i apply this, for example my query is something like this

```
from Pos in TableName
where Pos.vcr_Value >= Convert.ToDateTime("UserInputDate") //UserInputDate = 02/02/2011
select Pos;
```

If i try this it works

```
from Pos in TableName
    where Pos.vcr_Value == "UserInputDate" //UserInputDate = 02/02/2011
    select Pos;
```

But this just matches the date i want to get all the records after UserInputDate variable

**Note:**
This field store variable type of data sometime it save string sometime datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, your database design is fundamentally poor. Given that the column may not even be a date at all, you'd need to use DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact to write something which would work *in LINQ to Objects*. In LINQ to SQL that won't work as you'd need to use a lambda expression with a block as the body, and that can't be converted into an expression tree.

Furthermore, you've *also* got the problem of knowing what date format to expect - which is a natural corollary of storing dates in a text-based field instead of as a native date-based field.

If your date format were yyyy-MM-dd (or yyyy/MM/dd) it would be possible to do something which at least *approximated* the right query, by doing a string comparison, e.g. saying the value had to be between "2011-02-02" and "2099-12-31" for example. Even then it would match values such as "201 this isn't really a date".

If you don't have too many records, you could always do the filtering at the .NET side instead of in SQL - it's not ideal, but if you *have* to work with a broken schema, it's probably the most reliable option. If *at all* possible, however, you should change how you store the data.

Answer (score 1):

Fix you database.  Convert the varchar field to DateTime

Comment: This field store variable type of data sometime it save string sometime datetime.

Comment: This is a very poor database design and is what makes this such a problem. Do you at least have another column that indicates which rows are date times?  If not, the only way I can see to handle this is to pull all rows into memory and DateTime.TryParse on each row. Not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

check [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) There are answers how to convert and compare dates

HTH

Ivo Stoykov

PS: Steve is right. date format kept in DB as varchar is *very* bad practice!

Comment: Your link describe conversion in SQL Server but i want it in C# in a Linq query